# Find specific variables inside a function and return them sorted

Tags: python, function, sorting, variables

first of all, thank you for your help in forward. 
I'm using Python and I'm trying to search a .py file for all of its functions starting with the name "test_" and all of the variables included. The variables I search for are formatted like this: "var["blabla"]". So here I have an example:

def test_123:

```
    init = var["blabla1"]
    init2 = var["blabla2"]
    *somecode*
```

def test_456:

```
    init3 = var["blabla3"]
    init4 = var["blabla4"]
    *somecode*
```

What I already wrote is a script, that returns all my functions and variables in a html file. But I have to get them sorted, so I can work with them better.

Right now its like this:

```
test_123,test456
var["blabla1"],var["blabla2"],...
```

And I want it like this:

test_123:

```
var["blabla1"]
var["blabla2"]
```

test_456:

```
var["blabla3"]
var["blabla4"]
```

**EDIT:** I have this right now:

```
def suchentpar():
    fobj = open("2.py", "r")
    search = fobj.read()
    tpar = re.findall(r'var\[\"\w+\"\]',search)
    return tpar
    fobj.close()

def suchenseq():
    fobj = open("2.py", "r")
    search = fobj.read()
    seq = re.findall(r'test\_\w+',search)
    return seq
    fobj.close()
```

Comment: Is this a question about python or HTML? Because as far as I can understand, if you simply print the name of your method/class and of your variables in order while you execute them, they will be already in the order you asked for [provided that methods/classes don't call each other, of course].

Comment: Its about Python. Using the print would be easy for one file. But I have to work with hundreds of files. So an automation is preferred.

Comment: Clearly my question was not clear enough! ;) I understand that all you are asking help for is simply to reorder a series of strings: from `test1,test1,varA,varB` to `test1,varA,test2,varB`? If it is not the case, it would be helpful if you posted the code you already have, so that we can take a look and modify it.

Comment: I already edited my question. You can see the two functions that return the two lists. These two lists are filled with functionnames and variablenames. What I need is to sort these 2 lists, so I can instantly see which variable belongs to which function :)

Comment: Your patterns would match stuff like `footest_bar` or `blablavar[ ...`. Try adding word boundary checks with `\b`.

Comment: How did it turn out? Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much hochl and mac!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your code as is will never run `fobj.close()`, given that the functions will exit via `return` the line above...

Then, a way to obtain what you want could be:

```
import re

fcontent = '''
def test_a(self):
    var["hello"]
    var["world"]

def test_b(self):
    var["hola"]
    var["mundo"]
'''

dict_ = {}
chunks = [chunk for chunk in fcontent.split('def ') if chunk.strip()]
for chunk in chunks:
    tname = re.findall(r'test\_\w+', chunk)[0]
    vars = re.findall(r'var\[\"\w+\"\]', chunk)
    dict_[tname] = vars
for k, v in dict_.items():
    print k
    for e in v:
        print "\t%s" % e
```

**NOTE:** In the above code I left the regexes as you wrote them, but of course you could improve on them, and could change the first `re.findall` in `re.search` if you wished. In other words: what above is purely a demo to show the concept, but you should work on the edge cases and efficiency...

HTH!

Comment: That's some nice piece of code. Due to me being new to programming python I'm quite amazed by the simplicity!

Comment: @kory - If this is helpful, remember you can upvote the answer and eventually select it as "accepted" if it solves the problem for good. :) [maybe you know this already, but since you are new I thought to leave a note about it!] :o

Comment: To upvote your answer I need more reputation :). My current problem is that I have comments in my code that look like this: # ----- t e s t _ 123 ------ So I need to correct the findalls.

Answer (score 1):

This program will help you with the first part of your question, namely **finding all functions that start with `test_`**. You might expand it to find variable definitions of your choice as well, but this is a little more complicated.

The basic idea is to use the `ast` package to parse your Python source, and scan the result for function definitions. Thus, you won't detect **false positives**, for example a function definition inside of a string or comment. Example:

```
# define strings for function test_foobar().
foobar="def test_foobar(): pass"
```

This input contains two bad matches and would be detected by using regular expressions, if not *very* carefully crafted. Using `ast`, this is much simpler than you may think. Working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ast
import sys

def test_foobar():
        pass

class FunctionNameFinder(ast.NodeVisitor):
        def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
                if node.name.startswith("test_"):
                        print node.name, "on line", node.lineno

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as f:
        FunctionNameFinder().visit(ast.parse("".join(f.readlines())))
```

This program can be run on itself to detect the dummy function on line 6!

**EDIT:** The following extension will detect some variable assignments, but not all. Just to point out the direction.

```
        def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
                if node.name.startswith("test_"):
                        print node.name, "on line", node.lineno
                self.generic_visit(node)

        def visit_Subscript(self, node):
                if isinstance(node.value, ast.Name) and \
                   isinstance(node.slice, ast.Index):
                        if isinstance(node.slice.value, ast.Str):
                                print '%s["%s"] on line %s' % (
                                        str(node.value.id),
                                        str(node.slice.value.s),
                                        node.lineno)
                        elif isinstance(node.slice.value, ast.Num):
                                print '%s[%s] on line %s' % (
                                        str(node.value.id),
                                        str(node.slice.value.n),
                                        node.lineno)
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on previous answers, you can also use an OrderedDict (python 2.7+), to maintain the ordering.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

fcontent = '''
def test_a(self):
    var["hello"]
    var["world"]

def test_b(self):
    var["hola"]
    var["mundo"]
'''

dict_ = OrderedDict()
chunks = [chunk for chunk in fcontent.split('def') if chunk.strip()]
for chunk in chunks:
    print chunk
    tname = re.findall(r'test\_\w+', chunk)[0]
    vars = re.findall(r'var\[\"\w+\"\]', chunk)
    dict_[tname] = vars
print dict_
```

L.

Comment: I see you are new, so I hope you don't mind if I remark on the fact that when your contribution is a minor change to another users' answer you normally include it as a comment under the original answer. No harm done nor offence taken though! :)