# Find statements in a python file that have a chance to get executed

Tags: python, django

I am working on a opensource project where i implementing searching of "print" statements
and such other statements that are unnecessary in a live production enviroment and can 
create a error.
But i dont want to trouble the user if there is a print statement commmented out or "print" 
word in a docstring or a comment. So i am trying to find out those portion of the python
script that have a chance to get executed. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) module and `NodeVisitor` to analyze statically program's code. This way you will have no problems with docstrings or comments.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.6 or later you could probably use the ***ast*** module.  Read in the code (as a string, use ***ast.parse()*** to create an abstract syntax tree of that code, and then walk over the code looking for the *ast.Print* objects and then translate those back into filename, line number tuples.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thread is here:

[Check Python code for certain statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386016/check-python-code-for-certain-statements)

You can get some more ideas.